# Webkit: Flicker on CSS Transition with background image

Tags: css, css-transitions

The problem description refers to the following example: http://codepen.io/NilsWe/pen/yoksj

The background of the .main container flickers on the CSS transition in all webkit browsers.
Any of the solutions out there like:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

doesn't seem to work.

Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is a conflict between the position of the navbar and the main.

I have changed the positioning from float to absolute, and moved things changing left instead of margin-left; I think that now it works ok

CSS

```
.nav, 
.main {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5em 0 0 0;
  background: rgb(150,150,150);

  text-align: center;

  @include transition(margin-left 5s ease, margin-right 5s ease, left 5s ease);
}  

.nav {
  width: 30%;
  left: -30%;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background: rgb(200,200,200);
  background: url(http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5476/9299430029_08b1ea7494_h.jpg) no-repeat bottom center;
  @include background-size(cover);
}

/* ========== active state ========== */

.active-nav .nav {
  left: 0%; 
}

.active-nav .main {
  left: 30%;
  margin-right: -30%;
}
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/etGKv)

Comment: Thanks! Taking the navigation out of the document flow seems to work now in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing

```
 //-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 //-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

That has worked for me in the past.

Also the flickering can be caused by not defining the size of the manipulated element. Make sure you define the height and width of elements that are being manipulated.

Comment: totally, not defining the height of the element caused the flickering in my case, which was a svg background image. after a line of jquery I can define the height of the div and scrolling effect is smooth, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the width **and** height fixed the issue for me.